Thunderbird and Brave icons disappeared ubuntu 24.04
Thunderbird and Brave icons disappeared both on the pinned icons at left on desktop, and in the list of all apps

Eventually I opened Main Menu (install via Alacarte!) to look at Properties for Thunderbird and Brave, but nothing showed when clicking on Properties.
Below the table of apps is a button to Restore System Configuration.
Clicking on that restored the missing icons immediately.
